# Mi footer no se mueve cuando muestro un mensaje de advertencia

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

No estoy pudiendo hacer que mi `footer` se vaya para abajo cuando muestro un mensaje estilo `alert`.

Asi es como se ve mi `footer` sin el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero con el mensaje, el boton "Buscar" se ubica por debajo del `footer`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve probando con distintas `positions` pero no logro hacer que se mueva para abajo correctamente.

El estilo del footer es el mismo que el que viene por default cuando creas el proyecto:

```
   <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - Web
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Si veo en modo inspeccion (f12), se ve bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo `Bootstrap 5` para los estilos.

Comment: El footer no se debe modificar. Pero si el popAp que actúa como alerta: debe tener un z-index algo alto para que este sobre todos

Comment: mmm tampoco, le puse `z-index: 9999` y no funciona... para mi tiene que ver el `position` del `footer`

Comment: ¿Utilizaste la clase [`position-fixed`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/position/#position-values)?

Comment: Muestra el código en donde estás mandando a llamar el alerta. Revisa [ask] y agrega un [example]